# ZXing QR Reader Direct Integration android

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

Want to develop a QR code reader.. which will customized for my application. after a lot of search i found a link http://www.androidaz.com/development/zxing-qr-reader-direct-integration this tutorial demonstrate what i exactly want. but when i import it and then run this app i notice that its camera is in 90 degree angle when i rotate device. what is the problem i can not realize. my main.xml is

```
 <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="200dip"
        android:layout_height="200dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
         <include layout="@layout/capture"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

my mainactivity file is:

```
public class ScannerActivity extends CaptureActivity 
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_qrcode);
    }

    @Override 
    public void handleDecode(Result rawResult, Bitmap barcode) 
    {

        Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "Scanned code " + rawResult.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

menifest file with permission :

```
<uses-permissionandroid:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

<uses-permissionandroid:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<uses-permissionandroid:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

<uses-permissionandroid:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>

<uses-permissionandroid:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>

<uses-permissionandroid:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS"/>

<uses-permissionandroid:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<uses-permissionandroid:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>

<uses-permissionandroid:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

it can read QR code fine. only problem camera caused abnormal behavior when rotating..
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean when the camera is 90 degrees?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you would like to do is here:

**android-zxinglib**

**An android library project of zxing BarcodeScanner**

https://code.google.com/p/android-zxinglib/

Download the project and look these files:

- AndroidManifest.xml
- capture.xml

Answer (score -3):

Go into your manifest and change the orientation to landscape. Portrait caused the same problem for me, and landscape looked a lot better.